# como puedo comparar dos cadena en el mismo if

Tags: c

estoy creando un programa que va a comparar dos cadenas en un mismo if ya intente varias cosas pero el programa me lleva directo al "else" y tengo ese inconveniente,ya que soy nuevo en c, espero de su ayuda gracias.saludos.

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include<stdlib.h>
> #include <string.h>
>
> main()
> {
> char estado[2];
> char lexema[5];
>
>     printf("ingrese el estado \n");
>     fgets(estado,2,stdin);
>
>     printf("ingrese el lexema \n");
>     fflush(stdin);
>     fgets(lexema,5,stdin);
>
>
> //ceros
>
> if(strcmp(estado,"0") && strcmp(lexema,"+")==0){
> printf("estado 1");
> }
>
>
> else{
> printf("no se reconoce");
> }
>
>   getch();
> }
> ```

---

Comment: Puedes probar por separado los if e ir mirando que te devuelve en el strcmp, si entra al else es porque alguna condición no es igual.

Answer (score 0):

La función `strcmp( )` devuelve `0` si las cadenas son iguales, y `!= 0` si son distintas. Junto a eso, la [lógica booleana](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81lgebra_de_Boole) sale en nuestra ayuda:

```
if( !( strcmp( estado, "0" ) || strcmp( lexema, "+" ) ) ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Sólo tenias dos errores el primero es que no estabas validando que el valor de retorno de la primera comparación sea igual a cero, y por ultimo no limpiabas el salto de linea que agrega la función fgets al final de la cadena de caracteres ingresados por teclado, se arregla reemplazando el salto de linea por el caracter fin de cadena (\0) y lo otro es que cuando uses fgets, debes incrementar en uno al tamaño con que tienes pensado declarar el array porque fgets no utiliza el ultimo espacio.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void pedirCadena(const char *mensaje, char cadena[], int tam){
    int i = 0;

    printf("%s",mensaje);
    fgets(cadena,tam,stdin);
    fflush(stdin);

    while(cadena[i] != '\n' && i < tam) i++;
    cadena[i] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char estado[3];
    char lexema[5];

    pedirCadena("Estado: ",estado,3);
    pedirCadena("Lexema: ",lexema,5);

    //ceros

    if(strcmp(estado,"0")==0 && strcmp(lexema,"+")==0){
        printf("estado 1");
    }else{
        printf("no se reconoce");
    }

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```